# of dictators the world over from Julius Caesar onward

Tags: prepositions

> *The unnamed title character of Gabriel Marcia Marquez's The Autumn of the Patriarch is a composite figure not only of Latin America despots, but of dictators **the world over** from Julius Caesar onward.*

I would like to ask if the word "over" is used in the sentence as the preposition and if so why it come after the noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The world over" is a kind of idiomatic expression using a poetic inversion of the typical word order.  Here "over" does not mean "above" but rather "covering", as in *"You should put sunscreen all **over** (your body) before going outside"*

> [**The (whole) world over**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20(whole)%20world%20over) (phrase): *everywhere in the world, from all over the world.*

Examples:

> Although written in English, Rawling's books about her beloved boy wizard are known *the world over*.
>
> Although not originally native to many cultures, some form of bread is eaten *the world over*.

See also the similar idiom "around the world":

> The Louvre in Paris attracts tourists from *around the world*.
>
> Her books are famous *around the world*.

You can use a similar inversion with other nouns and prepositions, again as a kind of *poetic* device:

> The *dinner outside* was particularly nice as there was a full moon.
>
> Some philosophers speak of *"the garden within"* as a metaphorical place that needs regular care to avoid being overgrown with weeds.

Comment: Is "idiom" a cop out?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I don't think so? since it seems to be an ellipsis for the longer phrase "all over the world".  Similar is "the world below", a poetic expression, short for, "the part of the world below an elevated (physical or metaphorical) position".   But now that I think on it, this does seem to represent a somewhat *poetic* grammar structure, for example "the dinner outside", "the garden within" etc.

Comment: the long night through